# Selector always goes to disabled state by default in Android 5

Tags: android, android-selector

I have a `GridAdapter` with several items inside.

I've set the selector up like this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@integer/default_fade_duration">

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/greyDark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

And this is how I use it in the layout :

```
<SquareLinearLayout
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_transparent_grey">
    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>
</SquareLinearLayout>
```

I use this inside the `getView` in the adapter :

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        intf.onMenuClick(position, icon);
    }
});
```

But everytime I open up any activity which has that grid menu, the items are, by default, in `disabled` state even though it is actually enabled.

when I touch it, it goes to pressed state as usual, then if I drag and release my finger outside that view(cancelling my press), it goes to the default state.

What I want is that it goes to `normal` state by default, then `disabled` if it is actually disabled.

Comment: can you try setting the item to selected state in the adapter? so you could have something like a position or some flag on the basis of which you set the item selected inside the adapter

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Oh you mean doing `.setSeleted()` or set its state to `selected`? Let me try doing that, but after doing something else first, there are other things to do, sorry long reply